# Laravel: duplicate entries in foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a list feature that allows users to add specific articles to personalized lists. If i add more then one article to the same list. the list gets duplicated in the dropdown menu.

**Example:**

[image]

> The more articles i add to the specific list. so it duplicates.

**Database Tables**

```
list          | id | person_id  | name      | description
              | 1    15         | Test List | null

data_list_ref | id | list_id   | data_uid
              | 1  | 1         | 9b888e1e9e
              | 2  | 1         | jZ-mAtgh
```

**Query**

```
$lists = DB::table('list')
  ->leftJoin('data_ref_list', 'data_ref_list.list_id', '=', 'list.id')
  ->select('list.id', 'list.name', 'data_ref_list.data_uid')
  ->where('person_id', Auth::user()->person_id)
  ->get();
```

**Blade Implementation**

> $record->key is the current 'article' being viewed in the browser

```
@foreach($lists as $list)
  @if($list->data_uid === $record->key)  
     // show the checked list 
     // user's cant add the same article twice to a specific list
  @else
     // show the user's other lists
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: What dd(lists) produce?

Comment: @zloter it produces 2 items of the same list

Comment: @WesMurray can you please add ->groupBy('list.id') and try again.

Comment: @HarshSanghani thanx for the comment but still no luck

Comment: can you please add result here after applying groupBy?

Comment: that is the answer what I am ask you to add groupBy in your query bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Eloquent: Relationships.

Create 2 Models https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models
One for "list" and one for data_list_ref.

In the model "list" create a relationship with "data_list_ref" https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

include the model in your Controller like this

```
use App\List;
```

Now if you want to get the data from "List" and also from "data_list_ref" you call it like this

```
$list = List::where('person_id', Auth::user()->person_id)->get();
```

This is laravel's way of getting data.